How to Initialize SwiftData Instances Only on First App Launch?
I need some help with SwiftData. I want to have a few instances of one of my SwiftData classes created only the first time the app opens. These instances should be created once when the app opens for the first time, and not on subsequent launches. I've tried hard-coding them, but SwiftData is giving me issues with this approach. It seems like SwiftData requires instances to be created by the app itself, rather than being hard-coded. Is there a proper way to initialize these instances only on the first app launch?
I'm a beginner and would appreciate any help. Thank you!
That is the example for the Swift-Data-Class:
@Model
class TexEmoji {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var emoji: String
    
    init(text: String, emoji: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.text = text
        self.emoji = emoji
    }
}

That is the code I tried for the @main App
@main
struct PersonalAdviceApp: App {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    func checkFirstLaunch() {
            let hasLaunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")
            if !hasLaunchedBefore {
               let instance1: TexEmoji = TexEmoji(text: "Standard-Text 1", emoji: "")
               context.insert(instance1)
               let instance2: TexEmoji = TexEmoji(text: "Home-Page", emoji: "")
               context.insert(instance2)
               UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")
            }   
        }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestPage()
                .modelContainer(for: [Ergebnis.self, Seite.self, TexEmoji.self])
                .onAppear {checkFirstLaunch()}
        }
    }
}

Unfortunately I always get the following Error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot insert 'TexEmoji' in this managed object context because it is not found in the associated managed object model.'


Move the .modelContainer line down to become a modifier of WindowGroup

If I only move the .modelContainer one line down under the WindowGroup ist does not change anything. @vadian

Then do the check – including moving the context – inside the TestPage file.

That worked! Thank you so much.

Let the ModelContainer be a property in your app struct instead and do the set up in its declaration
var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([
        Ergebnis.self, Seite.self, TexEmoji.self
    ])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        checkFirstLaunch(context: container.mainContext)
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}()

With this set up I would recommend to call save() on the model context at the end of checkFirstLaunch.
And then you need to change the modifier in your Scene body property
.modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)


Note that instead of using UserDefaults another option is that you could check if values exists with a fetch. But of course that depends on the logic in the app if this is better or not.

Thank you so much! I tried to understand it, but it's still a bit hard for me, because I don't know much about ModelContainer etc. If the solution by vadian comes to a limit, I will try to understand your solution :)
